# how to add music library in my android application like facebook and twitter

Tags: android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, audio-player

I want to add or play mp3 files from music library in my application...

I am able to fetch all mp3 files in a listview but I want features of the music gallery which lists out the songs accroding to the albums,playlist,artist.

This is my code for fetching the mp3 files from SD Card

```
class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter {
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    currentPosition = position;
    playSong(MEDIA_PATH + songs.get(position));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check out the MediaStore and [MediaStore.Audio](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html) to be specific